# Could not find artifact jchem:jchem:jar:1.0 in central

Tags: maven

Help)Can any one help me in resolving the issue in Azure devops Pipeline

Error) I am getting the below error.

"Failed to execute goal on project gostar-mvc: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project org.springframework.boot:gostar- 
mvc:war:2.1.1.RELEASE: "

Could not find artifact jchem:jchem:jar:1.0 in central
My Query) I want the jchem:jchem:jar file to be added in the Azure Artifacts so that I can use the same in the CI pipeline. Is there any way to feed the jchem jar files into azure artifacts. Please Let me know. 
Thanks in advance

```
pom.xml file

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <artifactId>gostar-mvc</artifactId>
   <name>gostarnext-mvc</name>
   <description>gostarnext-mvc</description>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>

   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
           <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
           <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
           <version>4.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
           <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
           <version>3.17</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
           <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
           <version>3.17</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
           <version>2.6</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.2</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
           <version>2.1</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.json</groupId>
           <artifactId>json</artifactId>
           <version>20180813</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.freehep</groupId>
           <artifactId>freehep-graphics2d</artifactId>
           <version>2.4</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.freehep</groupId>
           <artifactId>freehep-graphicsbase</artifactId>
           <version>2.4</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.freehep</groupId>
           <artifactId>freehep-graphicsio</artifactId>
           <version>2.3</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.freehep</groupId>
           <artifactId>freehep-io</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.2</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.freehep</groupId>
           <artifactId>freehep-graphicsio-emf</artifactId>
           <version>2.4</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>jchem</groupId>
           <artifactId>jchem</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
           <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
           <version>1.4</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
           <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
           <version>2.9.2</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
           <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
           <version>2.9.2</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
           <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
           <version>1.10.19</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>
   <build>
       <finalName>gostarnext-mvc</finalName>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <excludeDevtools>true</excludeDevtools>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.19.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                   <includes>
                       <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                   </includes>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <!-- Added for Reporting . -->
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.17</version>
               <configuration>
                   <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
                   <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                   <includes>**/*.java </includes>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>checkstyle</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
               <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                       <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->

                           <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
                   <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created
                       after unit tests have been run. -->
                   <execution>
                       <id>post-unit-test</id>
                       <phase>test</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>report</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                           <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                           <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                           <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <!-- Added reporting -->
       </plugins>
   </build>
   <reporting>
       <plugins>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
               <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <reportSets>
                   <reportSet>
                       <reports>
                           <!-- select non-aggregate reports ... -->
                           <report>report</report>
                       </reports>
                   </reportSet>
               </reportSets>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </reporting>
   </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to use an artifact `jchem:jchem:jar:1.0` which is not in MavenCentral. So you need to configure (in your `settings.xml` or your POM), where Maven should search for it.

Comment: The Maven which im using is in Azure Devops as an agent. How can I view the Setting.xml